# Хранит ли DLL информацию о сигнатурах функций?

Tags: c++, c, dll

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хранит ли `DLL` информацию о сигнатурах функций?

Comment: Разве что mangled names. Но вот просто интересуюсь - а зачем это вам? :)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Harry видимо человек хочет пошалить и похачить)

Comment: Нет, я не хочу пошалить и похачить. У меня возникла необходимость разобраться в том, как это все работает. Например, влияет ли вложенность псевдонима простого типа экспортируемой функции на то, что попадет в `DLL`. А также меня заинтересовали вопросы портируемости и стабильности интерфейсов.